# SonarQube scan for specific modules

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

We have a project which is XML code base. We have Java and Javascript code written inside xml files. We are analyzing If sonar quality check can be done on Java and Javascript code. The plan is extract the code using script, put in workspace and run scan. The project has in-built version control system. We are not using tools like SVN or Git. Checkout the whole source code is not feasible. As we do incremental deployment, is there a way to run scan only on modified code? Next scan shouldn't run override the previous report on Sonar dashboard. It should update in the same project instead. Is it possible? Will scan work properly on extracted code?